January 2025 Photo Competition: Hygge
Here's the topic for this month:

Hygge (pronounced Hoo-ga) loosely translates to a sense of comfort, togetherness, and well-being (Danish). It is the pursuit of everyday happiness. Think cozy fireplaces, tea in a nook, coffee by candlelight, or listening to old records. What is Hygge to you?

It was suggested to me IRL by someone else, hence the quotation.
The contest will end at the end of January (UTC time). The following rules apply:

Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
You can make up to three posts (attempts).
Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
Keep it nice, CoC-compliant, non-offensive, and suitable for work.
If you have people recognizable in the photo, you must either (a) have their permission to post the photo or (b) make them unrecognizable.
If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
The photo may have been taken any time.
If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the list of possible photo competition topics. Also, you can join us in chat to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

